# Include external file with server_name

Tags: nginx, vhosts

My system needs to dynamically create vhots. To make the process easier, I created a file called names that contains the vhosts domains

```
#my path/names
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com
www.domain3.com
```

I need to include this file inside my nginx cong file
I need something like this

```
#/etc/nginx/sites-available/vhosts.conf
server {

        server_name ${include /path/names};
        ...
        ...
}
```

Is it possible to include an external file inside a server_name declaration?

Comment: Maybe research over on https://serverfault.com/